# Home Page outside of the site pages library

Tags: library, sitepages

I recently inherited a site collection that has been around for a while.  They recently upgraded to 2013 and their home page has been heavily customized and needs changed out.  It has been moved from the site pages library and is located under "all files" in designer.  I deleted that page, created a new one that has the 2013 look and feel and moved it out from under the Site Pages library and now the old URL will not work.  They did NOT want the URL to change, but I'm thinking that in 2013 the pages HAVE to be in the site pages library.  Am I correct?

Comment: Not necessary,  you can have it anywhere. All you need to do is set the welcome page from site settings.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished through SharePoint Designer 2013 as follows:

1. Open your site in SP Designer
2. Navigate to the page you want to be your home page
3. In the toolbar under the "Pages" tab, there is a subsection called "Actions"
4. Click the "Set as Home Page" button

Comment: yes - but then you add the /sitepages/xxx.aspx to the URL.   The current url is  https://xxxxx/default.aspx, not https://xxxxx/sitepages/default.aspx